# Java Web Services: sending files using DataHandler class

Tags: java, web-services, file

I'm new to Java Web Services, so I might be doing things wrong.

I'm trying to transfer a file using the DataHandler - this is what I've got:

Web Service:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMimeType;

/**
 *
 * @author pc1
 */
@WebService()
public class WSFileSender {

    @WebMethod( operationName = "getfile" )
    public @XmlMimeType( "application/octet-stream" ) DataHandler getfile( @WebParam( name = "path" ) String path ) {

        DataHandler datahandler = null;

        try {
            datahandler = new DataHandler( new URL( path ) );
        }
        catch ( MalformedURLException e ) {
            System.out.println( "Bad" );
        }

        return datahandler;
    }

}
```

Client:

```
package fileclient;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author pc1
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        try {
            fspg.WSFileSenderService service = new fspg.WSFileSenderService();
            fspg.WSFileSender port = service.getWSFileSenderPort();

            DataHandler handler = port.getfile( "FileSender/file.jpg" );

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "dest.jpg" );

            handler.writeTo( out );

            out.close();

            System.out.println( "Done" );

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO handle custom exceptions here
    }

    }

}
```

It seems, as if everything is being done correctly, but the file created is empty - what am I doing wrong?

================= EDIT ==================

The DataHandler object returned by getfile() is null - is it not possible to return this object from a webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DataHandler` returned is `null` my guess would be something goes wrong in that method (e.g. the `MalformedURLException` you are catching). If not, you could try to create the `DataHandler` in a different way, e.g. with a `FileDataSource` or a `ByteArrayDataSource`.

Comment: in the above approach is the entire data loaded into memory on the client side? Is there anyway to to stream it?